# want to show woocommerce webhook data in react.js application

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, socket.io, webhooks

what I want?
When someone does order from woocommerce then it show notification on my front end using React.js

What I tried?
I have setup webhook from woocommere > settings > webhooks for orders.created.

Now I want to watch for orders from woocommerce store that is: [www.martoo.com](http://www.martoo.com) and as someone do order it show notification on my front end that is React.js

Answer (score 0):

I was developing wms system for wooCommerce store and get stuck in a problem where i needed to receive push notification in react dashboard (data populated through api form wordPress wooCommerce) from wordpress wooCommerce and nothing was working fine. I tried webhookds, socket.io but could not get bread. SO finally i showed notifications through pusher. Kindly follow the steps and you will setup both backend and front very easily. Thank me later!

- Go at https://pusher.com/
- Click on "Get a free account". Then register yourself at it.
- Create a new App at the Channels tab.
- Write the name of your app anything you want.
- Choose ap2 (Asia Pacific(Mumbai)) or any other closer to the region of the website's owner on the cluster tab.
- Ignore everything else and click on create.
- Go to the apps tab in the navigation menu and click on the app you've created.
- Read documentation for further instructions